# How to receive cell highlight actions in UICollectionView subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to subclass a UICollectionView (not a UICollectionViewController), and I would like to know how I can set it up so that when the user highlights (or selects) a cell, the collection view can be notified, so I can perform a little animation on the cell. You may ask why I can't do that in a view controller. I chose to subclass UICollectionView so that it could be reusable. I am relatively new to iOS programming, and I would welcome any suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a block ^{}

Create a class with a **.xib** file. The .xib file will be used for each cell.

In your .xib file, add a clear UIButton, so that is on top of all your subviews. So the user can click on it.

In your .h file add

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^actionBlock)(void);
```

In your .m file add and link it to your UIButton in the .xib file

```
- (IBAction)showAnimation:(id)sender
{
    if (self.actionBlock) {
        self.actionBlock();
    }
}
```

Now in UICollectionViewController, cellForItemAtIndexPath, call the block

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCellClass *cell = 
        [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.actionBlock = ^{
//Here you have access to indexPath.section and indexPath.row
        NSLog(@"Going to animate the cell %@ x %@", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);

//do any other code for this specific cell
};

return cell;
}
```

Using action blocks, is like opening a portal into each cell, happy coding

Comment: Thanks, but can I set the UICollectionView to be the delegate of itself?

Comment: You could if you want but first I would let UICollectionViewController handle that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` is the view and `UICollectionViewController` is the viewController.

The `UICollectionView` you are subclassing is use for updating user interface with viewController's core logic to be triggered while highlighting (or selecting) the cell.
So you should set up the selected logic in your `viewController`.

If you understood Delegate Pattern, the normal way to update your `UICollectionView`'s cell while selected is using a delegate. When something triggered, call viewcontroller to do that for you.

Check out these links about
[Cocoa MVC Design Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) and [Designing Your Data Source and Delegate for CollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW1).